# How to center the labels in QGis?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a shapefile containing some US sections from the Public Land Survey System.
I would like to display the labels in the middle of the sections.

I found the "Placement" option in the "Label" sheet of the layer.

However, I am not succeeding in centering the labels. As you can see on the snapshot below, some labels are not centered properly :

[image]

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place your labels using the "Label Toolbar", not the Label tab in the Properties window for a specific layer.

Highlight the layer in the layer list (*single left-click*) and press the ABC button on the Label Toolbar:
[image: Label Toolbar in QGIS]

In the "Layer labeling settings" window, place a check beside "Label this layer with" and change the accompanying pulldown menu to the required label field.

Then in the "Advanced" tab under "Placement", change from "Around Centroid" to "Over Centroid".

[image: QGIS Label settings from the label toolbar]

Press OK and the labels should appear on the map centred.

Answer (score 3):

**For QGIS version 2.18:**

1. Double click on the layer in the *Layers Panel* to open the *Layer Properties* window
2. From the list of options in the left sidebar, select *Labels*
3. Select *Placement* from the internal left sidebar
4. Under the *Placement* section select *Offset from point*
5. Select the center quadrant

[image: Layer Properties Window with annotations]

Comment: When there are multiple lines, there is an alignment option. Choose `center`